# Defining an interface in Angular with constant values

Tags: angular

In Angular, how do you define an interface with constant values?  Ie, a 'State' interface which has all the states in Australia./

I can do this by:

```
interface State {
  name: string;
}
```

And then in my component:

```
states: State[];

this.states = [
        {name: "New South Wales"},
        {name: "Victoria"},
        {name: "Northern Territory"},
        {name: "Victoria"}
];
```

But I'd like to combine the initialisation into my Interface so that I can include this in multiple components.  What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you just define it as a constant? This isn't what interfaces are for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not define a service method to return a default value and call that method inside a constructor.

```
getState(): State[] {

   return [
        {name: "New South Wales"},
        {name: "Victoria"},
        {name: "Northern Territory"},
        {name: "Victoria"}
   ];
}
```

In component

```
constructor(private myService: MyService){
  this.state - this.myService.getState()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces are for defining properties, not constants.. constants are for defining constants..

```
interface State {  name: string }

export const STATES: State[] = [..all of the states]
```

then just import STATES where it's needed.  In an ideal world, you'd use something like immutable.js to ensure it's never mutated, but not much else you can do to prevent mutation unfortunately besides wrapping it in a service and protecting it that way.

Answer (score 2):

If your interface is just constant values of states, you could just use Enums for the states instead of the interface.

```
export enum States {
 SYDNEY= "SYDNEY", 
 MELBOURNE= "MELBOURNE",
 .....
}
```

and use this Enum where ever you want to access this values.

-- Edit

Plus, if you wanna add some more information to the interface, your could just do something like:

```
export interface StateDetails {
 name: States; // <--- which is the constant values from the enum.
 population: number;
 ... and so on. 
}
```

Comment: I'm using this in a select box, I won't get back the state text though, just the enum number value?

Comment: Will this give me an array?  I need to pass an array into the select box

Comment: You said you want a constant values of the states, so this is what the enum for, now you can make anything you want with this values.. you can make array and use this constant values. I just gave another approach to use constant values, since interface of one property of string is useless, and u could achieve this just by make an array of strings...